# $|f(z)|\le\frac{M}{|z|^{\alpha}}$ for all $z\in U_r(0)\setminus \{0\}.$ Why is $0$ a removable singularity of $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, estimation, singularity-theory

Let $0<r<1$, $f:U_r\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. Let $\alpha <1,\; M\ge 0$ such that $$|f(z)|\le\frac{M}{|z|^{\alpha}}$$for all $z\in U_r(0)\setminus \{0\}$. Prove that $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

I tried to prove it but I have no idea how to do it exactly. I would start with the Laurent-series of $f$ in $z_0=0$ : $$f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_kz^k$$ and the goal should be the prove $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$, i.e. $a_k=0$ for all $k<0$. First I have that $$\left|\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_kz^k\right|\le\frac{M}{|z|^{\alpha}}$$for all $z\in U_r(0)\setminus \{0\}$, but I don't know how to continue.

Therefore my question is: How to prove it (other ideas are welcome too) or how to continue?

Edit: With zhw's great hint I get (I wrote that as a comment, too) :  I have: $|zf(z)|\le \frac{|z|M}{|z|^\alpha} =M|z|^{1-\alpha}$ with $1-\alpha>0$. It follows $zf(z)\to  0$ for $z\to 0$. Therefore either $f$ has a pole in $0$ of order 1 or $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$. Is it correct? But then I am stuck again. If I assume, $0$ is a pole, I don't know where I get a contradiction.

Comment: for $z \in U_r^*$ :  $|f(z)| < M |z|^{-1+\epsilon}$. the idea is that $\ln |f(z)|  \sim a \ln |z|$ when $|z| \to 0$.  but if $a \not\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{-1\}$, $z = 0$ would be a branching point of $f(z)$ so it wouldn't be holomorphic on $U_r^*$ : thus $a \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{-1\}$ and with $a > -1$ it tells us that $f(z)$ is continuous at $z = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\,zf(z).\,\,\,$

Comment: Thanks! ok, I have: $|zf(z)|\le \frac{|z|M}{|z|^\alpha} =M|z|^{1-\alpha}$ with $1-\alpha>0$. It follows $zf(z)\to  0$ for $z\to 0$. Therefore either $f$ has a pole in $0$ of order 1 or $0$ is a removable singularity of $f$. Is it correct? But then I am stuck again. If I assume, $0$ is a pole, I don't know where I get a contradiction.

Comment: $zf(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0.$ Hence there is $g$ holomorphic on $U_r$ such that $g=f$ in $U_r\setminus \{0\}.$ Because $zf(z)\to 0, $ $g(0)=0.$ Therefore ...

Comment: I have a question about that. From where does the function $g$ come from? If $zf(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$ with $\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=0$, there exists a holomorphic function $h:U_r(0)\to\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $h(z)=zf(z)$ in $U_r(0)\setminus \{0\}$ and $h(z)=0$ if $z=0$. Then your $g$ must be $g(z)=\frac{h(z)}{z}$ in $U_r(0)\setminus \{0\}$ and $g$ satisfies that $\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}h'(z)=h'(0)$ exists. This is the only explanation I have how you get this $g$, but otherwise this function $g$ as above is not optimal because it has a removable singularity in $0$ as well..

Comment: That was a typo. $g(z) = zf(z)$ is what I meant.

Comment: Ahh okay, sorry^^. Therefore: $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{g(z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}g'(z)=g'(0)$ exists (I use L'Hospitals rule and that $g$ is holomorphic), hence $f$ has a removable singularity in $0$. Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe easier to say $zf(z) = g(z) = a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdots \implies f(z) =a_1 + a_2z + \cdots$